# Different ways to write singleton in Java

Tags: java, singleton

The classic of writing a singleton in java is like this:

```
public class SingletonObject
{
    private SingletonObject()
    {
    }

    public static SingletonObject getSingletonObject()
    {
      if (ref == null)
          // it's ok, we can call this constructor
          ref = new SingletonObject();
      return ref;
    }

    private static SingletonObject ref;
}
```

and we can add synchronized keyword if we need it to run in multithreaded cases.

But I prefer to write it as:

```
public class SingletonObject
{
    private SingletonObject()
    {
        // no code req'd
    }

    public static SingletonObject getSingletonObject()
    {
      return ref;
    }

    private static SingletonObject ref = new SingletonObject();
}
```

which I think is more concise, but strangely I didn't see any sample code written in this way, is there any bad effects if I wrote my code in this way?

Comment: In the second case, where you're statically initializing `singletonObject`, you can (and should) make it `final` as well, to guard against accidental modification.  (I tend to prefer static initialization too, for this reason.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The difference between your code and the "sample code" is that your singleton is instantiated when the class is loaded, while in the "sample" version, it is not instantiated until it is actually needed.

Comment: Of course the difference is usually irrelevant since java classes are loaded on demand.

Comment: And also the static initialization doesn't need to be synchronized.

Answer (score 18):

In the second form, your singleton is **eagerly** loaded and this is actually the preferred form (and the first one isn't thread-safe as you mentioned it yourself). Eager loading is not a bad thing for production code but there are contexts where you might want to lazy load your singletons, as discussed by the author of Guice, Bob Lee, in [Lazy Loading Singletons](http://crazybob.org/2007/01/lazy-loading-singletons.html) that I'm quoting below:

> First, why would you want to lazy load
>   a singleton? In production, you
>   typically want to eagerly load all
>   your singletons so you catch errors
>   early and take any performance hit up
>   front, but in tests and during
>   development, you only want to load
>   what you absolutely need so as not to
>   waste time.
>
> Before Java 1.5, I lazy loaded
>   singletons using plain old
>   synchronization, simple but effective:
>
> ```
> static Singleton instance;
>
> public static synchronized Singleton getInstance() {
>   if (instance == null)
>     instance = new Singleton();
>   return instance;
> }
> ```
>
> Changes to the memory model in 1.5
>   enabled the infamous Double-Checked
>   Locking (DCL) idiom. To implement DCL,
>   you check a `volatile` field in the
>   common path and only synchronize when
>   necessary:
>
> ```
> static volatile Singleton instance;
>
> public static Singleton getInstance() {
>   if (instance == null) {
>     synchronized (Singleton.class) {
>       if (instance == null)
>         instance = new Singleton();
>     }
>   }
>   return instance;
> }
> ```
>
> But `volatile` isn't that much faster
>   than `synchronized`, `synchronized` is
>   pretty fast nowadays, and DCL requires
>   more code, so even after 1.5 came out,
>   I continued using plain old
>   synchronization.
>
> Imagine my surprise today when Jeremy
>   Manson pointed me to the
>   [Initialization on Demand Holder
>   (IODH) idiom](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#dcl) which requires very
>   little code and has zero
>   synchronization overhead. Zero, as in
>   even faster than `volatile`. IODH
>   requires the same number of lines of
>   code as plain old synchronization, and
>   it's faster than DCL!
>
> IODH utilizes lazy class
>   initialization. The JVM won't execute
>   a class's static initializer until you
>   actually touch something in the class.
>   This applies to static nested classes,
>   too. In the following example, the
>   [JLS guarantees](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/execution.html#44557) the JVM will not
>   initialize `instance` until someone
>   calls `getInstance()`:
>
> ```
> static class SingletonHolder {
>   static Singleton instance = new Singleton();    
> }
>
> public static Singleton getInstance() {
>   return SingletonHolder.instance;
> }
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> **Update:** Credit where credit is due, [Effective Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/) (copyright
>   2001) detailed this pattern under item
>   48. It goes on to point out that you still have to use synchronization or
>   DCL in non-static contexts.
>
> I also switched singleton handling in
>   my framework from synchronization to
>   DCL and saw another 10% performance
>   boost (compared to before I started
>   using cglib's fast reflection). I only
>   used one thread in my micro-benchmark,
>   so the boost to concurrency could be
>   even greater given that I replaced a
>   heavily contended lock with a
>   relatively fine grained volatile field
>   access.

Note that Joshua Bloch now recommends (since Effective Java, 2nd ed) to implement singletons using a single-element `enum` as pointed out by [Jonik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/56285/jonik).

Comment: A drawback of the IDOH pattern is that if there's exception thrown in your constructor then it will not show up in your stack trace, thus makes it difficult to maintain. You'll only get java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Answer (score 10):

Well, in the latter case the singleton object gets created before it is ever needed, but in most cases that's probably not horribly bad.

By the way, Joshua Bloch recommends (in *Effective Java*, 2nd ed, item 3) implementing singletons using a single-element enum:

```
public enum SingletonObject { 
    INSTANCE;
}
```

He gives the following justification:

> [...] it is more concise, provides serialization
>   machinery for free, and provides an
>   ironclad guarantee against multiple
>   instantiation, even in the face of
>   sophisticated serialization or
>   reflection attacks. While this
>   approach has yet to be widely adopted,
>   a single-element enum type is the best
>   way to implement a singleton.

Comment: I read a few chapters of this book a long time ago, maybe I should read carefully this time

Comment: I'm not sure it's meaningful to provide " an ironclad guarantee against multiple instantiation, even in the face of ... reflection attacks". If an attacker is in a position to run a reflection attack, they completely own the VM and there's not really anything you can do about it. It's like quadruple-locking your front door and putting a sophisticated alarm system on it, while leaving the windows wide open.

Comment: @Steve: Yeah, it came out in 2008. Definitely a worthwhile (and much needed) update, even if the best parts of it remain largely unchanged from the 1st ed

Comment: Anon: the enum is just plain easier to write and read anyway, though.

Comment: @luksmir: You'd use the singleton instance like this: `SingletonObject.INSTANCE`

Answer (score 5):

I would say the latter code is the more standard pattern, actually. Your first version isn't thread-safe. Ways of making it thread-safe include synchronizing on every access, or *very carefully* making it use double-checked locking (which is safe as of the Java 5 memory model, so long as you get it right).

Note that due to classes being initialized lazily, your latter code would still only create an object unnecessarily if you called static methods on the class without wanting to create the instance.

There's a pattern using a nested class to do the initialization which can make this lazier, but personally the second form almost always does well enough for me on its own.

There are more details of this in Effective Java, but I don't have it with me to find the item number, I'm afraid.

Comment: +1 for hinting at issues with Double Checked Locking. -1 for missing the opportunity of pointing out the dangers of using singletons in the first place ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is that you're mixing singleton and lazy initialization. A singleton can be implemented with **different initialization strategies**:

- initialization on class loading
- lazy initialization that uses double checked locking
- lazy initialization with single checking (with possible repeated initialization)
- lazy initialization that uses the class loader (holder class idiom)

All these approaches are discussed in [Effective Java 2nd Item 71: Use lazy initialization judiciously](http://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&lpg=PP1&dq=bloch%20effective%20java&hl=de&pg=PT304#v=onepage&q=&f=false).

Answer (score 1):

the second way will solve multi-threading issue but will always create the Singleton even when you don't need it. The best way to do it is to create a Nested class.

```
public class singleton 
{
    private singleton() 
    {
       System.out.println("I'am called only when it's needed");
    }

    static class Nested 
    {
       Nested() {}
       private static final singleton instance = new singleton();
    }

    public static singleton getInstance() 
    {
       return Nested.instance;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) 
    {
      singleton.getInstance();
    }
}
```

Comment: [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to write a singleton class is given below .Please try it

```
public final class SingeltonTest {
    /**
     * @param args
     * @return
     */
    private static SingeltonTest instance = null;

    private SingeltonTest() {
        System.out.println("Rahul Tripathi");
    }

    public static SingeltonTest getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized (SingeltonTest.class) {
                if (instance == null)
                    instance == new SingeltonTest();
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Different ways to implement [singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) in java is as follows

```
public class SingletonClass {
private SingletonClass= null;    
public static SingletonClass getInstance() {
    if(SingletonClass != null) {
       SingletonClass = new SingletonClass();
    }
  } 
}
```

This is not thread safe. The following are `thread safe` implementation of singleton design pattern

**1. Draconian synchronization**

```
private static YourObject instance;

public static synchronized YourObject getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new YourObject();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

**2.Double check synchronization**

[Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking#Usage_in_Java)

```
private static final Object lock = new Object();
private static volatile YourObject instance;

public static YourObject getInstance() {
    YourObject r = instance;
    if (r == null) {
        synchronized (lock) {    // While we were waiting for the lock, another 
            r = instance;        // thread may have instantiated the object.
            if (r == null) {  
                r = new YourObject();
                instance = r;
            }
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```

**3. Initialization-on-demand holder idiom**

[Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom)

```
public class Something {
    private Something() {}

    private static class LazyHolder {
        static final Something INSTANCE = new Something();
    }

    public static Something getInstance() {
        return LazyHolder.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

**4. Other one is using enum**

```
public enum Singleton {
    SINGLE;
    public void myMethod(){  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Lazy loading enabled as well as thread safe
```

class Singleton {

```
                private static class SingletonHolder {
                public static Singleton instance = new Singleton();
                }

                public static Singleton getInstance() {
                   return SingletonHolder.instance;
                  }
               }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am declaring private constructor and static block so the purpose of static block is it will execute only once and inside a static block I am creating an object so constructor will be invoked only once.

```
class Demo {
  static Demo d=null;

  static {
     d=new Demo();
  }

  private Demo(){
     System.out.println("Private Constructor");
  }

  void add(){
    System.out.println("Hello I am Non-Static");
  }

  static Demo getInstance(){
    return d;
  }
```

}

Comment: Hello, here i am declaring private constructor and static block so the purpose of static block is it will execute only once and inside a static block I am creating an object so constructor will invoke only once.

Comment: Post your discussion as part of your Answer rather than as a Comment.

Answer (score -2):

I agree with Anon, and in the case where I always want to instantiate the singleton I would use

```
public class SingletonObject
{
public static SingletonObject REF = new SingletonObject();

private SingletonObject()
{
    // no code req'd
}
```

}

Comment: Danger: REF is a public non-final field. Could be replaced by subclasses. This model will also have problems if SingletonObject is Serializable. Just do the Effective Java thing, it's just as easy and sidesteps all this.

Comment: @Barett -I think Singleton can not be subclassed because it has private constructor.so subclasses will be asked to invoke super class constructor explicitly.

Comment: Inner subclasses are unlikely but possible. (BTW they can be created at runtime depending on the environment)