# Private constructor in singleton

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

```
 public class DBSingleton {

 private static DBSingleton instance = new DBSingleton();

 private DBSingleton() {
 // why do we need this constructor
 }
 public static DBSingleton getInstance() {
     return instance;
 }
}
```

How private constructor can help me?

I mean all variables and methods are static and even if I leave constructor public it will not change anything.
lets say someone create an object of my singleton nothing will happen because everything inside this class is static which means associated with the class itself not with object. Java static property is shared to all objects.

can anyone give me reasonable example please

Comment: First, singletons don't necessarily have to be implemented as classes with static methods. Second, when the object creation itself is heavy (CPU/network/etc) you want to control the number of instances that are created, like connection-pool for example.

Comment: Because if your constructor is public, anybody can call it, and thus create other instances of your singleton, which defeats the whole purpose of a singleton. If creating multiple instances is not a problem, why make it a singleton in the first place? If everything is static, why create even one instance?

Comment: This isn't even a singleton.`instance` isn't accessible without a creating a instance of `DBSingleton`, which in turn can't be done since the constructor is private. You probably meant `public static DBSingleton getInstance()`

Comment: @alfasin thanks for link but I did not find answer for my question, that was quite different

Comment: Agreed - the linked question isn't quite a duplicate. Answer incoming.

Comment: @JBNizet with public constructor everybody will be able to call it but it does not change anything  because they will access to the same fields. java`s static property is shared to all objects. is there any other reasons to make constructor private?

Comment: @Paul thanks it was typo fixed

Comment: As I said in another comment, if all fields and methods are static, there is no point at all in creating a singleton. You don't need any instance at all to access static members of a class. So making it a singleton makes it very confusing, and shows a lack of understanding. Making the constructor private, and not providing any getInstance() method, makes it clear that you should never instantiate the class.

Comment: @JBNizet In addition to not having a `getInstance` method, such a class should *ideally* be marked as `final` as well.

Answer (score 1):

A singleton class (edit: compare with *singleton instance* - see comments) doesn't even necessarily need to be instantiated; it's enough to give it a private constructor and declare all other methods static, forcing the user to invoke them on the class.

The constructor has to be private in order to ensure the class is a singleton, whether or not you create a single instance of it. If no private constructor were declared, Java would automatically provide a public no-arg constructor for it.

The class needs to be a single instance presumably for safety, namely, in cases where you want to invoke methods on it that do exactly what that singleton says they do. If you have an instance of a class that isn't explicitly made a singleton, then there's no guarantee when you invoke methods on it that it's running the singleton's implementation, because you might in fact have a subclass of `DBSingleton` in which said method is overridden. (If you invoke them as `DBSingleton.someMethod()`, you will of course get the expected behavior, but if you're doing this:

```
DBSingleton dbsInstance = DBSingleton.getInstance();
// ... all sorts of code, some of which might affect dbsInstance
dbsInstance.someMethod();
```

all bets are off.)

The more proper way to declare a class to avoid other instances of it is to declare it final. You give it a private constructor so that it also cannot be instantiated. (Either a final class or a class with a private constructor (or rather, zero non-private constructors) suffices to make the class non-overrideable.)

Comment: Having a class with zero possible instance and only static methods is fine, but it's definitely not a singleton.

Comment: @JBNizet it is a singleton in the sense that the users can use only the class (as an instance) and cannot create multiple instances of the same class.

Comment: Well, no, they can not use the class the same way as an instance of the class: no way to implement an interface if you only have static methods. No way to extend an abstract class. No way to store the instance in a collection, etc. etc. Anyway, singleton has a precise meaning, which is different from "utility class"? Using one word for the other doesn't bring anything other than confusion.

Comment: I agree with JB Nizet's points here, except that I think he's fighting history a bit - what he calls a "utility class" has been called a "singleton" in a lot of other places, and he's right that this is confusing. And I tend to see (mislabeled) utility classes far more often than true singletons, which makes it worse. I've been kinda slack about it myself. But this probably isn't going away any time soon.

Comment: @JBNizet  this discussion confuse me more )

Comment: What specific part of it is confusing you? I'm guessing the main source is from the word "singleton" being overloaded - there's the general sense of "something of which only one exists", and then the very precise technical sense of "the unique instance of a class designed to have only that instance", which is what JB Nizet is referring to. I was working off the more vague linguistic sense. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

You need a private constructor to prevent user from instantiating your class.

If you make your constructor public, users could do `DBSingleton singleton = new DBSingleton()` and your class will not be a Singleton!

Comment: yeah but it will not change much because java`s static property is shared to all objects. all fields were declared as static so even if user did DBSingleton singleton = new DBSingleton() he is going to access to the same fields. Am I right?

Comment: @M.T no. If all fields and methods are static, there is no point at all in creating a singleton. You don't need any instance at all to access static members of a class. So making it a singleton makes it very confusing, and shows a lack of understanding. Making the constructor private, and not providing any getInstance() method, makes it clear that you should never instantiate the class.

Comment: *"all fields were declared as static"* this is not the way to go  in Java. Since Java is an OO language you should use objects to benefit from polymorphism and abstraction via interfaces. If you think that's "overkill" then why are you using Java? There are lots of non OO-languages out there...

Comment: @JBNizet I did not quite get what you mean, I have provided getInstance method. Is there any other implementation of singleton design pattern in java without using static fields?

Comment: The whole point of a singleton is to have a unique **instance** of a class, with **instance** fields and **instance** methods. So that you can pass this instance as argument, implement an interface, etc. If all methods are static, having an instance is completely useless: what would you use it for?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle the only reason it's better to avoid it is that static is hard to mock and unit-tests. Other than that I don't think that using a class where  
"all fields were declared as static" is "against Java principles".

Comment: @M.T as for the question in your last comment, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879283/different-ways-to-write-singleton-in-java